# Shortcut to jump out of a c block

Tags: emacs

I am looking for an emacs shortcut/command to jump out of an c/c++ block. E.g.

```
int func(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == b) {
        cout << "Equal" << endl; // <-- I am here
    }
    // <-- I want to get here        
}
```

I want to use this keyboard shortcut in combination with yasnippet in order to jump out of the block after the if-statement. Ideally the move command would jump over pairs of braces and would ignore braces in comments.

I found C-M e which jumps out of the function, but I would only like to jump out of the block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>M-x up-list</kbd>, it also has an analog, <kbd>M-x backward-up-list</kbd>.  I don't believe either have default bindings.

Comment: `backward-up-list` is on C-M-up and C-M-u.  You can use C-h w to find bindings.